# Исходящие звонки только с первой сим карты

Tags: java, android

Как брать исходящие звонки только  с первой сим карты? Сейчас беру по умолчанию берет данные с двух сим карт.

```
 Cursor cursor =resolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, new String[]    
{CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.DATE, 
CallLog.Calls.DURATION, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_PHOTO_ID}, CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = " +     
CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE, null, CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

Comment: Дело в том, что хоть там 10 этих симок будет, но база данных для них одна, поэтому туда логаются все звонки со всех карточек. Я так понимаю телефон китайского происхождения? Если да, то всё может оказаться довольно грустно, если производитель но

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что хоть там 10 этих симок будет, но база данных для них одна, поэтому туда логаются все звонки со всех карточек. Я так понимаю телефон китайского происхождения? Если да, то всё может оказаться довольно грустно, если производитель - адекватная фирма, то возможно там будет поле в базе данных, которое отвечает за идентификатор симки, по которой можно узнать, с какой именно симкой происходило взаимодействие, но это мало вероятно, т.к. Android до 21 или 21 (Точно не помню) версии Api в принципе не поддерживал двухсимочность, поэтому двухсимочные телефоны, это уже допиленные прошивки от Google, а т.к. БД там скорее всего дефолтная, то возможно там и не будет данных о симке.

[Проглядите](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html) содержание полей БД, но как я увидел там нету ничего подобного по чём бы можно было бы идентифицировать симку.

Возможно для вас будет проще создать BroadcastReceiver, который будет реагировать на звонки и там уже определять симку, насколько я знаю, это более реально, можно будет получать данные об идентификаторе симкарты, помню сам делал нечто подобное и там по факту записывать в БД.